# Javascript array sort numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The below code is sorting numbers in an array, and the call back is making sure the numbers get sorted, but can someone explain what is the callback exactly doing?

```
var a = [2,4,7,21,34,52,88,5,2,6];
a.sort(function(a,b) {
return a-b
});
```

Also if someone can tell what are the uses of callback other than animation which is do other functionality only after the animation has finished.

Comment: [understanding callbacks in javascript](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

The function is a comparator, it returns `0` if the two input equals, less then zero, if a is lower than b, and greater than zero if a is greater than b. The `sort` method uses this function to determine the ordering between two elements.

You could write this too:

```
return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
```

This is equivalent in effect, but the other solution is much shorter, and actually easier to read.

An other answer mentioned bubble sorting, but this has *nothing to do with the actual sorting strategy*, thats up to the sort function, this is just the comparator for the sorting, nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

The callback is actually a comparator function which gives advantage how the developer wants to sort the array.

To arrange array elements in descending order,

```
a.sort(function(a,b) {
   return b-a
});
```